# How to make a circular progressBar like telegram?

Tags: android, telegram

I want a determinate circular progress bar like telegram android app but i cant find it in the project sources.

[image]

and it is rotating

[image]

**Update:** i am using [material progress](https://github.com/rey5137/Material/wiki/Progress) But it does not rotate in determinate mode, what i want is to rotate while loading... just like telegram app.

Comment: ok, there are tones of such libs on the github. https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android+circular+progressbar

Comment: Notice that the rotation happens when even progressValue is not changing.

Comment: https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/circular-progress-button + rotate it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a rotate.xml in res/anim folder:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1600"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

Load anim and run in code:

```java
view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.rotate));
```